# Moving a blog from Tumblr to Wordpress

Tags: import, tumblr

I want to move all my content, posts and pics from Tumblr to Wordpress ..! 
What would be the best way to do this???

Comment: Just an FYI: You probably want to improve this question a bit. Your title is "Moving the blogs from Tumblr to Wordpress" but the first sentence of the question is "Moving the blogs from Wordpress to Tumblr".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Tumblr Importer. :)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tumblr-importer/

Let me know if you have any problems with it, we're actively trying to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Tumblr offers a built-in export service, but you have some options through tools that use the Tumblr API.

- [Tumblr2WP](http://tumblr2wp.com/) can automatically export your Tumblr posts as an XML file. This is based from the Tumblr2WordPress project which is apparently no longer active, but is being hosted [here](http://haochen.me/tumblr/).

**NOTE:** You may get any number of errors when running this app because of API limits, especially if you have a large site. You might need to try a few times, I had to wait about 10 minutes before it would work for my site.  If you have your own web server with PHP, you can grab the [Tumblr2WordPress source code](https://github.com/benward/tumblr2wordpress) and run it yourself.

After you've exported your Tumblr blog to an XML file, you can use WordPress's built-in Import utility under Dashboard > Tools > Import in WordPress. You may need to tweak the formatting of your Tumblr XML file to get the best results, [this site](http://www.blogtips.org/how-to-import-a-tumblr-blog-into-wordpress/) may be a helpful reference if you experience problems.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have checked the websites and other details. As you are aware Tumblr has Reblogging features. I have dozens of reblogged contents .. whether it is possible to export reblogged contents also ..!

Comment: Wordpress doesn't import reblogged feature as it is tumblr specific.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has just included a New Tumblr import tool Which makes [moving Tumblr to WordPress](http://wpsites.net/site-move/moving-tumblr-to-wordpress/) very easy.

Comment: Thats great to hear