# Import post from Tumblr to Wordpress

Tags: import, tumblr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving the blogs from Tumblr to Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/moving-the-blogs-from-tumblr-to-wordpress)

Do know any way to import post from tubmlr to wordpress?

I have tried this http://www.tumblr2wp.com/ but it only imported 1 post and I have about 20 plus posts.

Need your help on this as soon as possible please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the Tumblr Importer. :)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tumblr-importer/

Let me know if you have any problems with it, we're actively trying to improve it.